# Shopify Cart Counter not showing align in Tablet (IPAD)

Tags: css, shopify, responsive

Hi i am trying to build shopify store everything goes perfect but there is 1 issue Cart counter is not showing align in IPAD.there is a class code which i am using 
   '

```
span.countPill {
    background: #f0e3d3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    right: 0;
}
```

i tried media query code is here

```
@media (min-width:767px) and (max-width:800px){
span.countPill{
background: #f0e3d3;
border-radius: 50%;
padding: 1px 6px;
font-size: 10px;
position: absolute;
top: 9px;
right: 0;
left: -3px !important
}
```

website link is [HERE](https://habitout.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the size 768ps to 991px keep width of new cart to 24px and change the padding and top in .navPages-mobile-container span.countPill class like i mentioned below:

```
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){
.new-cart {
    width: 24px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.navPages-mobile-container span.countPill {
    background: #f0e3d3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 1px 7px;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0;
}
}
```